# Connecting to CloudSQL through SSL using Sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, google-cloud-sql

I need to connect a node js app sitting on Lambda to a PSQL database in Google Cloud SQL.

The node js app uses Sequelize and I'm having trouble with finding any guidance on how to present the SSL information on sequelize.

This is what Cloud SQL wants me to specify:

```
  psql "sslmode=verify-ca sslrootcert=server-ca.pem \
      sslcert=client-cert.pem sslkey=client-key.pem \
      hostaddr=[HOST ID] \
      port=5432 \
      user=postgres dbname=postgres"
```

This is what I have currently on the node js app that keeps timing out:

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize(
  'postgres',
  'postgres',
  'password',
  {
    host: '[HOST ID]',
    dialect: 'postgres',
    dialectOptions: {
      ssl: {
        key: cKey,
        cert: cCert,
        ca: cCA,
      }
    }
  },
);
```

This is the error message I have been getting:

```
Unhandled rejection SequelizeConnectionError: connect ETIMEDOUT 35.232.250.60:5432
    at connection.connect.err (/Users/stephanielee/Desktop/blag/dist/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/connection-manager.js:154:24)
    at Connection.connectingErrorHandler (/Users/stephanielee/Desktop/blag/dist/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:174:14)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at Connection.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:442:20)
    at Socket.reportStreamError (/Users/stephanielee/Desktop/blag/dist/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:72:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:442:20)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:82:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:50:3)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

Comment: Is this using a public IP?

Comment: I have similar problem. I think you have to set public IP and add your IP address to whitelist. This partially works for me because I get connection but I still struggle with certificates